# make an insert action in a table without having the access right postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-grant, access-rights, database-trigger

i need to create a function that insert data rows in a table and make it executable for a user without giving the user the right to do any other action in the table ( no select or directly insert).
i tried with an insertion on a different table and trigger to move rows to the right table but it doesn't work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function with `SECURITY DEFINER` modifier. It will use grants of a user that created this function. then grant an execution rights to the limited user.

Details here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html